# Asp.net mvc open form with default value in field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have one field in my asp.net form that I would like to be initialized to 0.00 when the user clicks to create a new record.

Here is my model:

```
[DisplayName("Est Relocation Expense")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$", ErrorMessage = "The field Contract Price must be numbers and/or decimal point only")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public Nullable<decimal> Est_Relocation_Expense { get; set; }
```

Here is my create view:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Est_Relocation_Expense, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 CreateEditFieldNamesSpan" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Est_Relocation_Expense, new {@Value="0.00"})
<span class="CreateEditFormatExampleSpan">(Ex: 1000.00 with no commas)</span>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Est_Relocation_Expense)
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the code in the controller for create (get):

```
  // GET: /Utility/Create
    public ActionResult Create(int? ProjectID)
    {
        CreateDropDownListForCreateOrEdit(ProjectID);

        return View();
    }
```

I have searched, and I found posts saying to add the @Value parameter to the EditorFor helper. But, it isn't working. What am I missing? How can I accomplish this...it seems like it should be pretty easy to assign a default value to a form field. ??

Comment: Never override the `value` attribute. Use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Est_Relocation_Expense, "{0:0.00}")` (or you can add the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute as you did for the `DateTime` property

Comment: it's `DateTime` and you want to set `0.00`? anyway you should change `@Value` to `@value` i suppose

Comment: no, sorry, I copied the wrong field. It's relocation expense, not date, and should be set to 0.00. I'll try this.

Comment: This is my actual model:        
 [DisplayName("Est Relocation Expense")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$", ErrorMessage = "The field Contract Price must be numbers and/or decimal point only")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
        public Nullable<decimal> Est_Relocation_Expense { get; set; }
Would I just change the DataFormatString to "{0:0.00}"?

Comment: @NightOwl, Edit your question (not in comments) . And since you have `ApplyFormatInEditMode = false` then your `DataFormatString` will not be applied if you use `EditorFor()`

Comment: Oh, thanks...I edited the original post. I tried the first option (changing to TextBoxFor and adding the format, but it does not display the default value in the field (ie: when they choose add form, it should show 0.00 in the field as the default). Not sure why "ApplyFormatInEditMode" is set to false...can I change it to true? (I did not create this app...taking it over and trying very hard to learn MVC!).

Comment: @NightOwl, Have you set the value of `Est_Relocation_Expense = 0M;` in the controller before you pass the model to the view?

Comment: I added the controller code for the create. Not sure where to assign it...in the section right after if "(ModelState.IsValid)"?

Comment: Or, where I have "Estimated_Relocation_Date = UtilityDTO.Estimated_Relocation_Date", do I just change that to "Estimated_Relocation_Date = "0.00""?

Comment: @NightOwl (note how this message starts!). You need to set it in the GET method - `var model = new UtilityDTO(); model.Est_Relocation_Expense = 0M; return View(model);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am learning! :-) Really trying to get this. I added the first part, the Get method. Do you mean the section where all of the other assignments are (ie: under if (ModelState.IsValid) { ), or at the top in the Get, (ie: under CreateDropDownListForCreateOrEdit(ProjectID);)? Have read a lot of threads about get and post and what is happening here....still not sure, since there are already some definitions there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your GET method, replace `return View()` with the 3 lines of code from my last comment.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It worked! I feel like I should pay you for all your help! Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Now that you have edited your question with the controller code I can add an answer :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, except, it worked, but it didn't fill in the other fields that were being filled in...the utility id, project id below in the post method...the utility is added after selecting a project and it pulls those fields as keys.

Comment: You have not shown the model or the view code for those properties and I can't guess what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Okay, that is probably another question. :-) You definitely answered this one. Please add it as the answer so I can accept it/promote it. Thank you so much! (Oh, I see you did!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95994/discussion-between-night-owl-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should not attempt to override the `value` attribute generated by HtmlHelper methods. The reason that you do not get a formatted value in the textbox is that `Est_Relocation_Expense` is a nullable property and you have not set a value for it. Change the GET method to

```
public ActionResult Create(int? ProjectID)
{
    CreateDropDownListForCreateOrEdit(ProjectID);
    // initialize the model and set its properties
    UtilityDTO model = new UtilityDTO
    {
        Est_Relocation_Expense = 0M
    };
    // return the model
    return View(model);
}
```

Then in the view, use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Est_Relocation_Expense, "{0:0.00}")
```